# How can I get a rails controller to execute different javascript when called from different pages in my app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have sales_opportunities, these belong_to both users (whichever user input them typically), and also to companies (whichever company the sales_opportunity is selling to). I'm using Bootstrap 3 modals in order to capture the details of each sales_opportunity, and AJAX/JS to update the DB and then re-render partials on the same page with the new details (e.g. when a user adds a new sales_opportunity via the modal his sales pipeline gets re-rendered to show the newly added opportunity). All of this works fine so far.

What I also want to do is to have a page for the Companies within the system that the user is selling to. This page has basic details (e.g. company name and whether it's an existing customer etc). I also have a similar pipeline display so the user can see how many sales_opportunities they have with that particular company, and I want to re-use the modal above to enable the user to directly add a new sales_opportunity from the companies page, and then render some additional parts of that page with the updated information. This is where I'm running into problems, because my sales_opportunity controller tries to render create.js from the sales_opportunity file, and it seems to execute any js within that file, regardless of the target divs on the page I'm aiming for. Ideally I would be able to call one set of js if the AJAX request comes from the /users page and another if it comes from the /companies page - but I've not been able to deliver this.

In addition, I need to define @company in 2 different ways depending on whether the sales_opportunity is added via a user page (when they can select any company in the system or add a new one via AJAX) or via the company page (when it should obviously only add the opportunity to whatever company you were currently viewing).

Some code is below - please let me know if you need more:

Sales Opportunities Controller:

```
  def create
    @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.new(sales_opportunity_params)
    @pipeline_statuses = SalesOpportunity.pipeline_statuses
    @user = current_user
    @company = Company.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @sales_opportunity.save
    format.html { redirect_to @sales_opportunity.user, :flash => {:success =>  'Sales opportunity was successfully created.'} }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sales_opportunity }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @sales_opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render json: @sales_opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

create.js from the sales_opportunities view folder:

```
//code to work on the sales opportunity modal from the user view screen
$('#sales_opportunity_modal').modal('hide')
                    .clear_previous_errors();
                    resetForm($('#new_sales_opportunity'));
$input = $('#sales_opportunity_error');
$input.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.warning-block').html('');
  //render the newly added sales_opportunity only if the AJAX call succeeded 
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('#chevrons').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/users_chevron')%>");
  $(document).chevron_js()
  $('#sales-opportunities-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/sales_opportunities_table')%>");
// $("#sales-opportunities").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#sales-opportunities').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
    });
 });
//code to work on the sales opportunity modal from the company view screen
$('#company_sales_opportunity_modal').modal('hide')
                    .clear_previous_errors();
                    resetForm($('#new_sales_opportunity'));
$input = $('#sales_opportunity_error');
$input.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('.warning-block').html('');
//render the newly added sales opportunity only if the AJAX call succeeded 
 $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
 $('#single_company').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'companies/company_table')%>");
 $('#chevrons').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/company_chevron')%>");
 $(document).chevron_js()
 $('#sales-opportunities-table-div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/company_sales_opportunities_table')%>");
// $("#sales-opportunities").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#sales-opportunities').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
    });
 });
```

The details of the items being rendered probably don't matter, but for completeness the #chevrons id refers to a sales_pipeline display, the #sales_opportunities_table_div is just the exploded view of all the sales_opportunities and the #company_table is just the one line view of the company (e.g. name, whether it's an existing customer, current totals for sales made etc). That company table causes a failure in my rendering process currently, probably due to the fact that the sales_opportunities controller thinks @company is a new company rather than the existing one.

Can anyone help me understand this better please? In my thinking I'd define @company and render js from the users page (if the request came from there) and then define both differently if the AJAX request came from the companies page. However there may be a better alternative, and I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following code in the sales_opportunities controller:

```
    if @sales_opportunity.company.id?
      @company = @sales_opportunity.company
    else
      @company = Company.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])
    end
```

This doesn't totally solve this issue, as the create.js file ends up rendering items that aren't even on the page, but I should be able to fix that using:

```
if (/companies/.test(self.location.href)) { ... };
```

Or similar to ensure the js code will only render the items relevant to the companies show page.